# Scapy: Sending forged Probe Requests and capturing them in a different device

Tags: wireless, forensics, network-scanners, python

**Objective:**

Sending a forged Probe Request frame from one machine and capturing it on a second machine.

I have two codes running:

**sender.py**

```
interface = sys.argv[1]

dot11 = Dot11(addr1='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', addr2='11:11:11:11:11:11', addr3='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
probeReq = Dot11ProbeReq()
dot11elt = Dot11Elt()

frame = RadioTap()/dot11/probeReq/dot11elt
sendp(frame, iface=interface)
```

**receiver.py**

```
interface = sys.argv[1]

def packetHandler(pkt):
    if(pkt.haslayer(RadioTap) and pkt.haslayer(Dot11)):
        dot11 = pkt.getlayer(Dot11)
        if(dot11.addr2 == "11:11:11:11:11:11"):
            rssi = str(radiotap.dBm_AntSignal)
            print("Received Probe Request with rssi = " + rssi)
while True:
    sniff(iface=interface, prn=packetHandler, store=0)
```

---

**Problem:**

The receiver don't always gets the packets.

When I use the loop=1 parameter on sendp() it usually takes around 5k sent packets until the receiver catches a single one.

I've used wireshark to ensure that all Probe Requests are being sent, however, my receiver program seems to ignore most of them, is this a normal behaviour for scapy? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you positive both interfaces are transmitting and receiving on the same channel? This is not controlled from your code.

Comment: Not really, I completely forgot about that. Setting both interfaces to the same channel solved the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the code you are using doesn't check or set the wireless channel for either transmitter or receiver. If they are not on the same channel, they cannot communicate.

Since you have success *some* of the time, there could be other daemons that are hopping channels (e.g. scanning for available networks). For your code to work, you will need to kill other daemons that are using your wireless card, and force the channel with:

```
iw dev <interface_name> set channel <channel>
```

The `airmon-ng` utility can print out processes that may be using your wireless card.